# NodeJS: how to read file line by line like in Python

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Python, we can read in a file line by line in a very neat way:

```
with open("filename") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        #handle your line
```

Just curious whether there is a similar way in NodeJS/Javascript to achieve this.

The closest way in NodeJS/Javascript I know is:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var stream = require('stream');

var instream = fs.createReadStream("filename");
var outstream = new stream;
var rl = readline.createInterface(instream, outstream);

rl.on('line', function(line) {
  // handle your line here
});
```

Thanks

Derek

Comment: You can read the entire file, then split it by line break and the loop it.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-by-line

Comment: @Ziki, if the file is large, you may run out of memory very quickly.

Comment: @Vlad-miller, good to know the package. But not as neat as what I expect.

Comment: I know, but with real all the file and then split it it's the same as you mentioned in your Python code. I don't see any reason to use something else(like library, e.x. line-by-line), then the native option that you mentioned. Please explain why you look for a different solution?

Comment: @derek there is no syntactic sugar for this is nodejs. You can also try lazy.js

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `line-by-line` npm

It is useful for reading large files as it does not buffer the file data.

It pauses the stream when it receives the data chunk, emits event for all lines in current chunk, retains the leftover portion of last line. Then it resumes back the stream and merges the leftover portion with new chunk and repeats the process.

You can check it source code from [here](https://github.com/Osterjour/line-by-line/blob/master/line-by-line.js)

Below, is code snippet for example:

```
var LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line'),
    lr = new LineByLineReader('big_file.txt');

lr.on('error', function (err) {
    // 'err' contains error object
});

lr.on('line', function (line) {
    // pause emitting of lines...
    lr.pause();

    // ...do your asynchronous line processing..
    setTimeout(function () {

        // ...and continue emitting lines.
        lr.resume();
    }, 100);
});

lr.on('end', function () {
    // All lines are read, file is closed now.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my line-reader library if you prefer: https://github.com/bilaloguz/secureWebServer/blob/master/line_reader.js

In my experiments, for 1 million line text file, reading and writing to the console line by line took 218 seconds with Python, 111 seconds with Nodejs (Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: Note that the link here is now dead.